# Dialog some após ser aberta

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou usando uma dialog do primefaces:

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" modal="true" resizable="false">
        <p:outputLabel value="Mensagem qualquer."/>
        <p:commandButton value="Botão 1" action="#{chama um método no ManagedBean}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Botão 2" action="#{chama um método no ManagedBean}"/>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:link value="Abrir caixa de diálogo." onclick="PF('dialog').show()"/>
<h:form>
```

Estava a observar quando passo o mouse por cima do `<p:link/>` o endereço da página aparece no rodapé, como se fosse um redirecionamento.

Porque isso acontece? Não existe nenhuma URL. Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando escreve um `<p:link>`, o *markup* gerado é um link para a própria página.

Caso a intenção seja apenas ter o link como estética, não para navegar, basta dar um `return false;` após todo processamento que faz no `onclick`, dessa forma irá bloquear o comportamento padrão que é navegar.

O resultado seria:

```
<p:link value="Abrir caixa de diálogo." onclick="PF('dialog').show(); return false;"/>
```

Se deseja usar um `<a>` apenas por estética, seria melhor utilizar um `<span>` e estilizar de forma a se parecer com um `<a>`.

Comment: O único problema é que também está congelando a página se o modal estiver ativado.

Comment: Está dando algum erro no console do browser ou do servidor?

Comment: Nada em nenhum dos dois.

Comment: @Patrick, fiz um teste com esse código e não vi problema nenhum. A ação do `Bean` é executada? O que você quis dizer como congelada? O modal não é fechado após a ação?

Comment: Não dá pra fazer nada na tela, como se fosse um printscreen da tela. A ação do bean não executada porque não chego nem a clicar no botão.

Comment: @Patrick, então tem outro problema no seu código. Sugiro criar outra pergunta, fechar com um mcve com o código da sua `View` e o seu `Managed Bean` que reproduza o problema, porque pode destoar do objetivo principal dessa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o p:link vira a tag `<a>` e no HTML quando essa tag não recebe nenhum link se considera que o link é o da página atual.

exemplo

```
<a href="">clique aqui</a>
```

vai direcionar para a propria página, para resolver isso coloque uma hashtag no link

```
// no seu caso
<a href="#" onclick="PF('dialog').show()">Abrir caixa de diálogo.</a>
```

Por que não sei se isso funcionaria:

```
<p:link outcome="#" value="Abrir caixa de diálogo." onclick="PF('dialog').show()"/>
```

Tente e dê um feedback. :)

Comment: `outcome="#"` deu erro. `href="#"` não deu erro, porém congelou a página. Coloquei o modal como falso e parou de congelar, porém não é interessante para mim deixar sem essa propriedade. Creio que agora o problema envolve o modal. Existe algum *workaround*?

Comment: acredito que a solução do Wakim será a alternativa correta caso queira utilizar o p:link